# List all subcategories based on main category id

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I need to get all categories id which belongs to specyfic category. Is possible to list all subcategories categories based on main category id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `Category` class you'll see a method named `getSubCategories()`:

```php
/**
  * Return current category childs
  *
  * @param integer $id_lang Language ID
  * @param boolean $active return only active categories
  * @return array Categories
  */
public function getSubCategories($id_lang, $active = true)
{
    [...]
}
```

So if you have a `$category` object and want all active subcategories to print on front you can do:

```php
if (isset($this->name[Context::getContext()->language->id]))
    $id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
else
    $id_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
$subcategories = $category->getSubCategories($id_lang, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from prestapyt import PrestaShopWebServiceDict
from xml.etree import ElementTree

URL = ''
API_KEY = ''

cat_list = []

def get_categories(category_id):

    prestashop = PrestaShopWebServiceDict( URL, API_KEY )

    try:
        # get first childrens
        categories = prestashop.get('categories', category_id)['category']['associations']['categories']['category']

        for category in categories:
            print "main cat: " + category['id']
            cat_list.append(category['id'])

            try:
                # get second childrens
                categories = prestashop.get('categories', category['id'])['category']['associations']['categories']['category']

                for category in categories:
                    print category['id']
                    cat_list.append(category['id'])

            except:
                print "Category " + str(category['id']) + " has not children."

    except:
        print "Category " + str(category_id) + " does not exist."


get_categories(98);
```

Additionally I created something like this by api, but this show only one children but I must request two times (I do not need lower levels).

Comment: As it is not fully related with the initial question. Could you create a new question with this specific problem?

Comment: This completely solve my problem, but by adding new levels of code declare how deep to look.